# API Gateway v2 (HTTP API) mock integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

Is it possible to create a mock integration with API Gateway v2, similar to how API Gateway v1 works?

I would like to define my routes and integrations with lambda functions and have the $default route return a static 404 response without creating a lambda function to handle the unexpected route request.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer for "Is it possible to create a mock integration with API Gateway v2" is no. Each API Gateway route must be integrated with an AWS service, HTTP API or VPC link.

But, it is possible to have the $default route return 404 by simply not creating an integration for it. API Gateway will then return a response with 404 status code and body `{"message":"Not Found"}`